# Is it okay to cast off for neckline near crosses (cables)?

Tags: knitting

My wife is knitting me this wonderful cabled sweater pattern: https://knitrowan.com/en/free-patterns/cole and she is about to finish the back panel. However, the very last RS row before casting off for the neck has a Cr12F and a Cr12B in it. Then there was a WS row, and then casting off for the neck. Before she continues doing the front as well, the cast-off stitches look a bit twisted because of these two large crosses. Will this fix itself when picking up these cast-off stitches and knitting the ribbing around the neck, or will this cause a strangely twisted shape in the whole neck? If so, what is the best way to fix this?

E: added a picture[image: The neckline in question with the crosses and the twists]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the photo of the front, there is a crossing in the cable just two rows below the cast off/pick up for the neck.

I would go with the pattern, and see how the stitches work out in the casting off.
When you see them pulling so much that you do not like it you can unpick that bit of casting off, drop all the stitches of the cable, let them run down to just below that last cross and pick them up in knit without the twist. A crochet needle and a (short) cable needle will make the picking up easier.

Alternatively, you can just forget to make that last crossing, (not following the pattern,) but do so on both sides of the front and/or back, not just on the left or on the right (easy mistake to make.)
You can make the last crossing on the front but not on the back, if you think that is best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the ideas. I have added a picture to the question of how it looks. As you can see,the cross is quite a lot nearer to the neckline than in the pattern's picture. We anticipate the front will be cast off in a similar spot. It's a real shame there are no pictures of the model from the back!

Won't it look weird if you just don't do the cross? She thought she'd have to undo quite a bit of the last pattern (and put in some scrap yarn just in case to make picking them up easier)

Comment: The look should change a bit when she blocks it too.

Comment: could she block it with the piece of scrap yarn in it? Or will that pull that row out of shape?

Comment: Forgot about this, and wanted to update you on how it turned out: she went with the pattern as per this answer. Picking up stitches for the neckline was a bit difficult, but it worked and looks very nice.